# SL Loney Coordinate Geometry Potential Error?

Tags: geometry

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrKmc.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWMU7.jpg)

These are two screenshots from SL Loney's Coordinate Geometry text. I don't see how the points P and P2 both have the coordinates (-a,b). They are on different quadrants and clearly are at different horizontal distances from the origin. Can someone please clarify this for me, because it really makes no sense.

Comment: Post the whole page.

Comment: Ok, I will. But, please, can someone answer my question? Every time I post a question here, there's something wrong with it, and, not ever, do I actually get a good answer. I'll fix the question, but I just want an answer.

Comment: In my opinion, it is a typo.

Comment: The book mostly uses $P_2$; the one $P$ there is typo, it should be $P_2$. By notation of book, it is clear that $P_2$ is a point in second quadrant, $P_3$ in third, etc.

Answer (score 0):

without print error it should read

..the coordinates of P are $(-a,b)$ and the position of $P_2$ is given by the symbol $(0,b)$.